# Fragment vs Activity with LinearLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I have a dynamic UI that I need to generate and I would like to know what the best approach would be to do this and why? The application that I need to make will either way only have a single activity in which to display various different views which are generated by code, so not in an XML file.

So basically I want to draw one set of views and have a user interact with them (textview, button, radio button, edittexts etc). Then save the data he generated, clear the canvas or screen and within the same activity generate the next set of views for the user to interact with.

I have done extensive research and I know that I can use either a Fragment or an Activity with a LinearLayout to achieve this, but I am not sure which would be better and why?

Thanks,
Wihan

Comment: why are you don't want to create xml layout and creating your view through code.

Comment: Based on "generate the next set of views" I think you should use fragments, and switch to another fragment for "the next set" you refer to, instead of switching activity.

Comment: Because I have to, the layout is not know at compile time as they want a UI which is generated once the app is running.

Comment: @Tapirboy I am not switching activity as stated above. If I don't use Fragments I will just clear the LinearLayout and create more views in the same Activity.

Comment: What part of your UI is changing at runtime, maybe you could consider simply hiding/showing views when needed? As for displaying a single screen, there's no advantages of using a Fragment unless you have a top level navigation and want to be able to easily switch screens (i.e. display settings)

Comment: Well I need to have a blank layout to which I add items at runtime. So the app needs to fetch a file from a server which will say it needs to have so many items on screen 1, then by pressing a next button it needs to have so many items on screen 2 and so on and so forth. So at runtime I receive the file and it says there needs to be 50 items in total displayed, I then need to display the first few, press a next button, display the next few and so on until I have displayed all of them. They can be anything from a textview to a radio button to an edittext etc.

Comment: @jmcdonnell40 The App needs to fetch a file from a server at runtime that will have data that the App needs to display. So lets say it has 50 items for the App, the App must then take these items  (radio button, textview, edittext etc) and display them all. But the screen on which they display in the App must not scroll, so I can only display a few then by using a next button it must display the next ones until all have been displayed. Think of something like a survey that needs to be conducted with the information entered needing to be stored. Hope that makes sense?